# Efficient way to try retrieving data based on set date, and if it doesn't work, shift 1 day earlier

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I have a csv file of S&P 500 holdings as of the end of each year for 15 years (i.e. 12/31/1999-12/31/2015). Therefore, the dataframe has 15 columns of holdings. I am trying to write a code that will loop through each column of holdings, take those holdings and gather the price data at multiple points (i.e. current, 3 months from the current period and 6 months from the current period). The current period is always the title of the specific column being looped through (e.g. 12/31/2014).

I am using DataReader with FinanceYahoo to pull the price data. I am trying to find the most efficient way to do this. One challenge is, the financeyahoo API needs a date to be a trading date (i.e. can't be a weekend). Therefore, I have used try/excepts to try the date and if it doesn't work, go one day back. I do this up to 4 times because that should be enough to get to a trading day. I am wondering if this is slowing it down a lot. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I am yet to get the code to run the whole 15 years because it takes a half hour to do 1 year and when I tried overnight it crashed.

```
equities = (sample data is below)

prices = DataFrame()
for col in equities.columns[16:18]:
    temp = DataFrame(equities[col])
    temp.rename(columns={col:'ticker'},inplace=True)
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(col,'%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    temp = DataFrame(temp['ticker'].dropna())
    temp = DataFrame(temp['ticker'].map(lambda x :str(x)[:-3]))
    temp['calendardate'] = date
    datetemp = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    splicestart = 0
    splicenum = None
```

## Current Price

```
    try:
        datecur = datetemp
        tempprice = DataFrame(
            DataReader(temp['ticker'][splicestart:splicenum], 'yahoo', datecur, datecur)['Adj Close']).transpose()
        temp = temp.merge(DataFrame(tempprice[datecur]), how='outer', left_on=temp['ticker'], right_index=True)
        temp.rename(columns={datecur: 'current'}, inplace=True)
    except:
        try:
            datecur = datetime.datetime(datecur.year,datecur.month,datecur.day-1)
            tempprice = DataFrame(
                DataReader(temp['ticker'][splicestart:splicenum], 'yahoo', datecur, datecur)['Adj Close']).transpose()
            temp = temp.merge(DataFrame(tempprice[datecur]), how='outer', left_on=temp['ticker'], right_index=True)
            temp.rename(columns={datecur: 'current'}, inplace=True)
```

I do a few more try/excepts for that specific period and then repeat for 3 months late (see code below):

## 3 Months Price

```
try:
        datecur = datetime.datetime(datetemp.year + 1, datetemp.month - 9, datetemp.day)
        tempprice = DataFrame(
            DataReader(temp['ticker'][splicestart:splicenum], 'yahoo', datecur, datecur)['Adj Close']).transpose()
        temp = temp.merge(DataFrame(tempprice[datecur]), how='outer', left_on=temp['ticker'], right_index=True)
        temp.rename(columns={datecur: '3month'}, inplace=True)
    except:
        try:
            datecur = datetime.datetime(datecur.year, datecur.month, datecur.day - 1)
            tempprice = DataFrame(
                DataReader(temp['ticker'][splicestart:splicenum], 'yahoo', datecur, datecur)['Adj Close']).transpose()
            temp = temp.merge(DataFrame(tempprice[datecur]), how='outer', left_on=temp['ticker'], right_index=True)
            temp.rename(columns={datecur: '3month'}, inplace=True)
```

Again, 2 more try/excepts are done just shifting 1 day earlier.

Many thanks for any help!

## Sample Data

```
12/31/2012,12/31/2013,12/31/2014,12/31/2015  
A UN,A UN,A UN,A UN  
AA UN,AA UN,AA UN,AA UN  
AAPL UW,AAPL UW,AAPL UW,AAL UW  
ABC UN,ABBV UN,ABBV UN,AAP UN  
ABT UN,ABC UN,ABC UN,AAPL UW  
ACN UN,ABT UN,ABT UN,ABBV UN  
ADBE UW,ACN UN,ACN UN,ABC UN  
ADI UW,ADBE UW,ADBE UW,ABT UN  
ADM UN,ADI UW,ADI UW,ACN UN  
ADP UW,ADM UN,ADM UN,ADBE UW  
ADSK UW,ADP UW,ADP UW,ADI UW  
ADT UN,ADS UN,ADS UN,ADM UN  
AEE UN,ADSK UW,ADSK UW,ADP UW  
AEP UN,ADT UN,ADT UN,ADS UN  
AES UN,AEE UN,AEE UN,ADSK UW  
AET UN,AEP UN,AEP UN,ADT UN  
AFL UN,AES UN,AES UN,AEE UN  
AGN UN,AET UN,AET UN,AEP UN  
AIG UN,AFL UN,AFL UN,AES UN
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a business-day index (excludes weekends)
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html

```
pd.bdate_range(start, end)
```

You can generate business-days like the example below:

```
In [44]: start = datetime(2011, 1, 1)

In [45]: end = datetime(2012, 1, 1)

In [48]: rng = pd.bdate_range(start, end)

In [49]: rng
Out[49]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-03', '2011-01-04', '2011-01-05', '2011-01-06',
               '2011-01-07', '2011-01-10', '2011-01-11', '2011-01-12',
               '2011-01-13', '2011-01-14',
               ...
               '2011-12-19', '2011-12-20', '2011-12-21', '2011-12-22',
               '2011-12-23', '2011-12-26', '2011-12-27', '2011-12-28',
               '2011-12-29', '2011-12-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=260, freq='B')
```